# Canvas Not Rendering Properly: Why?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I was trying to construct an RPG out of html5 and Javascript with the `<canvas>` element; but I ran across a real stumper of an error: my code does not modify the `<canvas>` element at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>BoxRPG</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Box RPG</h3>
        <canvas id="rpgCanvas" width = "200" height = "100" style = "border:1px solid #FF0000;">failMessage</canvas>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            var c = document.getElementById("rpgCanvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out this! Am I just being stupid and missing the obvious or is there some deeper problem with either code or my system.

Comment: so what's the error? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fill style is not a fill command , you have to specify area to fill :

```
var c = document.getElementById("rpgCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/ms7Lg/

if you seek advice , leave this all and start learning

http://jonobr1.github.io/two.js/

or maybe

http://snapsvg.io/

Comment: ofcourse it does exist !! i said it is not the command to fill , it is just the command to style your fill !

Comment: Oops... That is really embarrassing: hours of research down the drain (yes, I really did study this); Thank you. (P.S. sorry about earlier comment)

Comment: if my answer solves your problem , kindly choose it as correct answer.